# Porque o e-mail fica mal formato ao colocar HTML no corpo?

Tags: asp.net, string, envio-de-email

Tenho um editor jQuery que envia para o meu input uma string no Formato HTML da seguinte forma.

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">Prezados,</span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">Informamos a publicação da <strong><em>Instrução Normativa IBAMA 10</em></strong>, de 25 de junho de 2014, que altera a </span><span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">Instrução Normativa IBAMA 21, de 26 de dezembro de 2013, que d</span><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">isciplina o Documento de Origem Florestal (DOF).</span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">O DOF é utilizado para realizar transporte, beneficiamento, comércio, consumo e armazenamento de produtos florestais de origem nativa, inclusive o carvão vegetal nativo; o local de armazenamento dos produtos florestais, o transporte e recebimento desses produtos, a conversão de produtos florestais por meio do processamento industrial ou processo semi-mecanizado e os processos de exportação e importação de produto florestal.</span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">A IN IBAMA 21/13 havia determinado que:</span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: 35.4pt; text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><em><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">Art. 35 - A partir de 1º de janeiro de 2014, o acesso ao Sistema DOF disponibilizado às pessoas jurídicas poderá será realizado por meio de certificação digital, em caráter facultativo.</span></em></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: 35.4pt; text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><em><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></em></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: 35.4pt; text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><em><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">§ 1º A certificação digital será obrigatória a partir de 30 de junho de 2014 para a validação de acesso dos usuários mencionados no caput, cabendo a esses providenciarem seus próprios certificados conforme especificações a serem fornecidas pelo Ibama.</span></em></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">A IN IBAMA 10/14 alterou esse prazo e assim modificou a redação acima:</span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: 35.4pt; text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><em><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">Art. 35. A partir de 4 de agosto de 2014 o uso de certificação digital para validação de acesso ao Sistema DOF será obrigatório, cabendo aos usuários, pessoas físicas ou jurídicas, providenciarem seus próprios certificados conforme especificações fornecidas pelo Ibama.</span></em></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: 35.4pt; text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><em><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></em></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-left: 35.4pt; text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><em><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">§ 1º Até que se inicie a obrigatoriedade prevista no caput, o uso da certificação digital é facultativa.</span></em></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">A consolidação da IN IBAMA 21/13 com as alterações promovidas pela IN IBAMA 10/14 será disponibilizada na Atualização de Julho de 2014.</span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;">Atenciosamente,</span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="text-align: justify; text-autospace: none;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt; font-family: 'Arial','sans-serif'; color: #282526; mso-fareast-language: PT-BR;"> </span></p>
<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="color: #1f497d;"> </span></p>
```

Porem ao enviar um e-mail o espaço entre um paragrafro e outro
é de mais ou menos 5 espaços.
Alguém sabe o que teria de errado nisso?

Código da `Envio`:

```
            MailMessage emails = new MailMessage();
            emails.IsBodyHtml = true;

            ContentType mimeType = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/html");

            AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(Mensagem, mimeType);
            emails.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

            emails.IsBodyHtml = true;
            emails.Subject = Assunto;
            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
            if (!HttpContext.Current.IsDebuggingEnabled)
                client.Send(emails);
            else
                EnviaEmailDebugHtml(emails.Subject,htmlView);
            htmlView.Dispose();
            return true;
```

Comment: Qual a bibilioteca usada para enviar o e-mail?

Comment: SmtpClient MailClient = new SmtpClient(); MailMessage emails = new MailMessage();

Comment: Creio eu que seja o span ou o paragrafo!!
Segue imagem do texto. [inserir a descrição da imagem aqui](http://i.stack.imgur.com/I9zFZ.png)

Comment: Qual o símbolo usado para o parágrafo? `\n`, `<br />` ou `<p></p>`?

Comment: O simbolo é <p>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Faltou você especificar no seu objeto `MailMessage` que o corpo do e-mail será [html](/questions/tagged/html). Procure também evitar colocar HTML dentro da propriedade `Body`, porque não funciona muito bem. Crie uma `AlternateView` no lugar:

```
MailMessage emails = new MailMessage();
emails.IsBodyHtml = true;

AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(seuHtmlVindoDaTela, new ContentType("text/html"));
message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

MailClient.Send(emails);
```

Fonte: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Bom, aí você tem que forçar mais umas tags extras. Possivelmente o formatador está tomando algumas liberdades extras pra formar esse e-mail.

Comment: @Marconi Possivelmente.